# Does VI v4.0 on Solaris 2.5.0 have a command history

Tags: solaris, vi

I normally use VIM but have to fiddle with files in VI. Does the vi on Solaris 2.5 have history I can recall to re-use commands? It's a pain to retype complete lines sometimes. In VIM I can go ESC, ESC, Up-Arrow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is unfortunately no history support in the SVR4 release of `vi`.

Note it is not `vi` version 4 but "Version SVR4.0, Solaris 2.5.0". This version string is hardcoded and reported even in recent releases (Solaris 2.5 is something like 18 years old).

Starting from Solaris 11, `vim` is bundled with the OS.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to replay keystrokes in `vi` as a macro, if this is sufficient for your needs. This can be done in two ways.

In both cases, I'll lead with similar content for `vim` and then differentiate for `vi`.

## 1. Register Macros

These are captured and replayed interactively.

### 1.1 vim

Recall that in `vim`, a macro is created by recording a series of keystrokes to a register in recording mode (reached from command mode). Then the macro is executed by executing the contents of the register.

```
qa                # 1. Enter recording mode, will save to register "a.
  ihello<esc>     #    Type key strokes to insert string "hello".
             q    #    Return to command mode.

@a                # 2. Execute contents of register "a (insert "hello").

@@                # 3. Repeat last macro execution (insert "hello").
```

As the question is asked, these steps wouldn't be utilised in `vim`, rather you'd use the application's command histories.

### 1.2 vi

In `vi`, step 1. above is performed in a different way: the macro contents must be typed in a buffer in insert mode and then yanked/copied/etc into a register.

```
i                            # 1a. Enter insert mode.
 ihello<ctrl-v><esc>         #     Type key strokes to insert string "hello", escaping necessary keys.
                    <esc>    #     Return to command mode.

"aY                          # 1b. Yank entire line to register "a (macro text should appear on a line by itself).

@a                           # 2. Execute contents of register "a (insert "hello").

@@                           # 3. Repeat last macro execution (insert "hello").
```

## 2. Key Mappings

These can be captured interactively or in the appropriate `*rc` file.

When executing a mapping, both `vim` and `vi` wait 1 sec (default) to accept all keystrokes that constitute the mapped word.

### 2.1 vim

```
:cmap lhs rhs<enter>    # Map rhs-words to lhs-word for command-mode mappings.
:imap lhs rhs<enter>    #                           for insert-mode mappings.
:map! lhs rhs<enter>    #                           for command- and insert-mode mappings.
:map  lhs rhs<enter>    #                           for normal-mode mappings.
:nmap lhs rhs<enter>    #                           for strict normal-mode mappings.
                        # Escape necessary keys in lhs and rhs.
                        # lhs "#n" means function key "n"
                        # Use vim's extensive symbolic key names.

:vmap                   # Other variants
:xmap
:smap
:omap
:lmap

:unmap lhs              # Remove map
:nunmap                 # Other variants
:vunmap
:xunmap
:sunmap
:ounmap
:unmap!
:iunmap
:lunmap
:cunmap
```

#### 2.1.1 Example

Make the `q` key write and exit the editor, exploiting `vim`'s symbolic key names.

```
:nmap q :wq<CR><enter>     # <CR> is typed as 4 chars, <enter> as 1.
```

### 2.2 vi

```
:map  lhs rhs<enter>    # Map rhs-words to lhs-word for command-mode mappings.
:map! lhs rhs<enter>    #                           for insert-mode mappings.
                        # Escape necessary keys in lhs and rhs.
                        # lhs "#n" means function key "n"

:unmap lhs              # Remove map
```

#### 2.2.1 Example

Make the `q` key write and exit the editor.

```
:map q :wq<ctrl-v><enter><enter>
```

## References

1. The `vim` documentation, eg: [here](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/).
2. **An Introduction to Display Editing with Vi**, by the authors of `vi`, eg: [this PDF](https://docs.freebsd.org/44doc/usd/12.vi/paper.pdf).